# Loadbalancer IP and Ingress IP status is pending in kubernetes

Tags: azure, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubeadm

I have created the Kubernetes Cluster using two Azure Ubuntu VMs. I am able to deploy and access pods and deployments using the Nodeport service type. I have also checked the pod's status in `Kube-system` namespace. All of the pod's status showing as `running`. but, whenever I mention service type to Loadbalancer, it was not creating the LoadBalancer IP and it's status always showing as `pending`. I have also created an Ingress controller for the Nginx service. still, it is not creating an ingress Address.  While initializing the Kubernetes master, I am using the following command.

`kubeadm init`

Below is deployment, svc and Ingress manifest files.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: test-ingress
 spec:
   backend:
     serviceName: nginx
     servicePort: 80
```

```
$ kubectl describe svc nginx

 Name:              nginx
 Namespace:         default
 Labels:            app=nginx
 Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"nginx"},"name":"nginx","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"p...
 Selector:          app=nginx
 Type:              ClusterIP
 IP:                10.96.107.97
 Port:              http  80/TCP
 TargetPort:        80/TCP
 Endpoints:         10.44.0.4:80,10.44.0.5:80,10.44.0.6:80
 Session Affinity:  None
 Events:            <none>
```

```
$ kubectl describe ingress nginx
Name:             test-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  nginx:80 (10.44.0.4:80,10.44.0.5:80,10.44.0.6:80)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  `*`     `*`     nginx:80 (10.44.0.4:80,10.44.0.5:80,10.44.0.6:80)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"test-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"backend":{"serviceName":"nginx","servicePort":80}}}
Events:  `<none>`
```

Do we need to mention any IP ranges(private or public) of VMs while initializing the kubeadm init? or
Do we need to change any network settings in Azure Ubuntu VMs?

Comment: You need to provide more details, such as the output of the command `kubectl describe svc`. It would gives the error which the service meet.

Comment: Can I see the yaml file for your deployment? how did you expose the service port? did you use  ```externalIPs:``` to define the desired IP address?

Comment: Hi Charles Xu and Anuradha Fernando. I have added output of the command `kubectl describe svc` and deployment and service yaml manifest files in the Question?

Answer (score 2):

As you created your own Kubernetes cluster rather than AWS, Azure or GCP provided one, there is no load balancer integrated. Due to this reason, you are getting IP status pending.

But with the use of Ingress Controller or directly through NodePort you can circumvent this problem.

However, I also observed in your `nginx service` you are using an annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb` and you said you are using `Azure` and those are platform specific annotations for the service and that annotation is AWS specific.

However, you can give something like this a try, if you would like to experiment directly with public IPs, you can define your service by providing [`externalIPs`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips) in your service if you have a public ip allocated to your node and allows ingress traffic from somewhere.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
  externalIPs:
    - 80.11.12.10
```

But, a good approach to get this done is using an `ingress controller` if you are planning to build your own Kubernetes cluster.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Binary Bullet. Thanks for the response. I have updated my Question. Can you please check that once?

Comment: Ok let's try to debug, what's the actual issue now after adding ingress controller. To start with first `curl 10.96.107.97:80` and see if your `svc` is able to talk to `pods`. And if it works, then next part is debugging comms part between `ingress` and `svc`. And I could see your ingress  doesn't have paths. While it would be good to know if ingress controller is working or not. I mean are comms from `www` reaching ingress controller.